# swap column using dataframe in csv file- Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to swap columns from csv file using dataframe in s3 bucket. **Dataframe** has header row which has column name(`sa_instance_state, data_interval_start,NAME`)

**My piece of code**:

```
def modify_csv(**kwargs):
    s3=boto3.client('s3')
    read_file = s3.get_object(Bucket=Bucket, Key=Key)
    df = pd.read_csv(read_file['Body'],sep=',')
    print(df)
```

**Input dataframe** (`print(df)`)

```
sa_instance_state     data_interval_start  NAME 
<sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState1> 2022-07-17 12:55:00+00:00  XYZ
<sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState2> 2022-07-17 12:58:00+00:00  abx
```

**Expected Result:**

```
NAME  sa_instance_state     data_interval_start   
XYZ   <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState1> 2022-07-17 12:55:00+00:00  
abx   <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState2> 2022-07-17 12:58:00+00:00
```

Comment: What have your tried so far?

Comment: I am trying to find a way to swap column based on first row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df = df[['NAME', 'sa_instance_state', 'data_interval_start']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set_index` and `reset_index`:

```
>>> df.set_index('NAME').reset_index()
  NAME                      sa_instance_state        data_interval_start
0  XYZ  <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState1>  2022-07-17 12:55:00+00:00
1  abx  <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState2>  2022-07-17 12:58:00+00:00
```